# Navigation bar pushing down video and controls

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, frame

Summary: I'm wondering why the MPMoviePlayerController is being pushed down by the navigation bar in landscape orientation.

In my iOS app I have a simple tableView. When I tap a cell I **modally** present an instance of myViewController wrapped in a UINavigationController. myViewController has an instance of MPMoviePlayerController as a subview.

The moviePlayer and associated controls are being pushed down and slightly off the bottom of the screen. I can fix this by hiding the navigation bar. However I want to show the navigation bar with the video.

**What's the best/correct way to prevent the video and controls from being pushed down and slightly off screen?**

I've looked at the frame of the moviePlayer, the frame of the myViewController's view etc and am still a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also set your view's `autoresizingMask`? On the other hand if you want the navigation bar to cover part of your view, then set the `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`.

Comment: Good point about the `autoresizingMask`. I'll try that. The nav bar style is currently black and translucent is set to YES.